# Ssh key management in AWS like gcp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, amazon-iam

Google Cloud really Nails the SSH Key Management thing out of the box and AWS leaves it all up to you.

In gcp your gcp login credentials are also used for SSH access. gcp automatically creates SSH keys on your user's behalf and uploads them to the instances when you SSH into them. So no manually generating SSH Keys trying to keep them safe and keep track of them. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

How can I roll something like this myself for AWS? Not even sure where to start looking what kind of product this would even be.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using OpsWorks Stacks. It's in their documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/security-ssh-access.html

Otherwise you have to share the private key since there will only be a single key pair if you are using EC2 key pair.